# Sum of series $\frac{x^{3n}}{(n+1)}$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

I'm asked to find the interval of convergence of this series:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{{x}^{3n}}{n+1}$$

and then the sum of the series.

**Attempted Solution:**

Clearly the series converges when $\vert x \vert<1$.

I put $x^3=y$  so that now we have:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{{y}^{n}}{n+1}$$

knowing that $\frac{y^n}{n+1} = \frac{1}{y}* \int y^ndy$ we can rewrite the series as:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{{y}^{n}}{n+1} = \frac{1}{y}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int y^ndy= \frac{1}{y}\int\sum_{n=0}^\infty y^n = \frac{1}{y}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-y} =\frac{-1}{y}*ln(1-y) $$

In conclusion 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{{x}^{3n}}{n+1}=\frac{-1}{x^3}*ln(1-x^3) $$

Does this make any sense?

Comment: Yes, a perfect explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea, but execution is a little sloppy. Start with
$$\frac{y^n}{n+1}=\frac1y\int_0^yt^ndt$$
Then
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{y^n}{n+1}=\frac1y\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_0^yt^ndt=\frac1y\int_0^y\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}t^ndt=\frac1y\int_0^y\frac{dt}{1-t}=-\frac1y\ln(1-y)$$
Where we have relied on uniform convergence of the sum for $0<y<1$.

See the difference? You didn't know what to take as the upper limit for the integral because $y$ was already the variable of integration so you chose $\infty$ and actually created a divergent integral, which could invalidate your proof.